# How to convert esModule code to TypeScript use tools?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

Is there a tool or library available to convert JavaScript code back to TypeScript/ES? The project contains many `[name].js` and `[name].js.map` files with code similar to this example:

```js
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const tslib_1 = require("tslib");
const models_1 = require("../../models");
const utils_1 = require("../../utils");
const function_1 = tslib_1.__importDefault(require("./function"));
const CheckTokenQueue = (0, function_1.default)('CheckTokenQueue');
...
```

The `tsconfig.json` file is configured as follows:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src"],
}
```

Comment: Typically, in a file like that, vs code for example will offer to the module syntax for me automatically. To manually translate the code correctly, you just need to understand the differences between the two module systems which you should anyway. Note that the conversion here is not between TypeScript and JavaScript but between esm and presumably commonjs